# SqlDataReader.HasRows return always "true" even with empty result

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, mysqldatareader

After browsing a multitude topics on the phenomenon of `SqlDataReader.HasRows` which always returns true even with empty result (and especially when it is about an SQL query with an aggregate), I dry completely on my code

However my example is very simple and `HasRows` returns `True`, `FieldCount` returns `1` even when there is no phpMyAdmin side line.

```cs
query = "SELECT FK_BarId FROM tlink_bar_beer WHERE FK_BeerId = " + sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);

MySqlConnection sqlConnexionList = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=beerchecking;uid=root;password=;");
MySqlCommand commandList = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlConnexionList);
sqlConnexionList.Open();

int[] BarsIds;
using (MySqlDataReader sqlDataReaderList = commandList.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (sqlDataReaderList.HasRows)
    {
        try
        {
            BarsIds = new int[sqlDataReaderList.FieldCount];
            int counter = 0;

            if (sqlDataReaderList.Read())
            {
                while (sqlDataReaderList.Read())
                {
                    int id = sqlDataReaderList.GetInt32(counter);
                    BarsIds[counter] = id;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlDataReaderList.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        BarsIds = new int[0];
    }
}

sqlConnexionList.Close();
```

Do you know how to get HasRows false when there is no rows like in phpMyAdmin result?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What happens when you run your query directly with SQL studio? I'll bet it returns a single row.

Comment: Something seems to be amiss. The query is constructed getting an ID from a `sqlDataReader`, so I assume the ID exists and you therefore have rows? `FieldCount` returns the number of columns and since the query has one column `FK_BarId` you'd always get 1.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use an auxiliar DataTabe instead DataReader, something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(commandList.ExecuteReader());

if(dt.Rows.Count > 0){

    //rows exists
}else{

    //no rows
}
```